# Iterating over a set of elements in CPLEX OPL

Tags: linear-programming, integer-programming

I am trying to model the following constrain in OPL. Here πG is string set.

$$ r >= \sum_{k=1}^{Np-1} y(k,k+1)  \quad \quad \quad \quad           
∀p∈ πG $$

Here is how I tried it in CPLEX OPL,

```
tuple Path {{string} nodes;}

{Path} paths = ...;

subject to{

 forall(p in paths)
        sum (node in p.nodes) Y[node][next(p.nodes,node)]  <= r;

 }
```

since i want to iterate till N-1 th element of set and apply function Y for k+1 th element i used "next" function. But here it iterates till N th element. Is it possible to do it using OPL notation to iterate till N-1 th element and get the k+1 th element in function?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Thanks Jose. It looks way easy to read now.